# VBA - Localizar celda por nombre de encabezado y nombre de fila, y no por letra/número

Tags: vba

Llevo varios días intentando descubrir cómo asignar un valor a una celda concreta usando VBA, pero en lugar de utilizar las coordenadas del excel (B4, D9..) o bien (5,6 - 6,9 - etc.), utilizar el nombre de la fila y de la columna, es decir, usar la primera fila como encabezado, y la primera columna como índice, para poder localizar de forma dinámica las celdas que me interesan, ya que no siempre estarán ubicadas en las mismas coordenadas.

Es decir, en lugar de hacer esto:

```
Range(Cells(4, 5), Cells(8, 9))
Range("C4")
Cells(4, 6).Value = variable_x
```

Poder hacer algo así:

```
Cells("ID374839", "SALARIO")
```

Donde ID374839 sería el ID de la fila, y "SALARIO" el encabezado de la columna.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrías incluir en tu pregunta un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) como para poder entender qué es lo que llevas días intentando.

Comment: Nose si hay una manera de hacer directamente lo que pides, pero lo que puedes hacer es buscar la fila en la que se encuentra tu id, y la columna del salario. Luego simplemente utiliza los numeros para cambiarle el valor

Comment: Esto suena muy bien, buscar en la fila y en la columna que quiero usar como índices los valores que necesito, y luego extraigo sus posiciones para saber la coordenada de la celda que me interesa. Lo probaré, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de unos días encontré la forma más correcta de encontrar un campo a partir de los valores del encabezado y de la primera columna, lo expongo a continuación:

```
Sheets(1).Select

Range("A5").Select
fila = Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown)).Find("Antonio", ActiveCell, , , xlByRows).Row

Range("B4").Select
columna = Range("B4", Range("B4").End(xlToRight)).Find("PRIMAS", ActiveCell, , , xlByColumns).Column

Cells(fila, columna).Copy Range("H11")
```

En la variable "fila" almaceno el índice de la fila donde se encuentra el trabajador "Antonio" (el nombre sería en este caso su ID). Y en la variable Columna almaceno el índice de la columna donde se encuentra la columna de "Primas". De esta forma conoceré la prima de Antonio (100) haciendo, por ejemplo, "Cells(fila, columna).Copy".

[image: Tabla del ejemplo]

La utilidad reside en que los trabajadores cambian y no siempre pueden estar ubicados en la misma fila, por lo que así puedo localizarlos dinámicamente y modificar los valores que necesite.
Posteriormente, uso los valores recabados para obtener el valor de la celda localizada y copiarlo en otro lugar.

Para más información de cómo trabajar con esta función, que se llama "Range.Find", recomiendo la página donde hallé esta solución:

[Range.Find en VBA](https://www.excel-avanzado.com/39919/range-find-en-vba.html)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tu deseas se puede obtener asignando cada columna a constantes y de esta manera hacer referencia en forma dinámicas a ellas. Te lo muestro con un ejemplo:

```
'Asignas el nombre de una columna a una constante.
Const COLUMNA As String = "A"
```

Ahora asignando el nombre de una fila a una variable, por ejemplo:

```
'Asignamos el numero de fila a un Entero Largo
Dim fila As Long
```

De esta manera, podremos hacer referencia en forma dinámica a las celdas de esta manera:

```
Celda.Range(COLUMNA & fila)
```

Answer (score 0):

El objeto Cells no se suele utilizar, pues ofrece pocas opciones. Lo más lógico es utilizar Range. Mira este artículo:
[Objeto Range](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))

En cualquier caso, ¿lo que necesitas es esto?

```
Public Sub Rango()
Dim Rango As Range

Set Rango = Range("A2")
Rango.Name = "NombreRango"
Rango.Value = 12345678
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]